# Text limit for Google DLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I can't seem to find the text size limit for de-identifying text

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/limits said there's a 4KB limit for each quote.

What does quote means ? Does it mean a string ?

Answer (score 0):

De-identifies potentially sensitive info from a ContentItem. This method has limits on input size and output size.

When you de-identify data using the CryptoReplaceFfxFpeConfig or CryptoDeterministicConfig the input value must be :

- At least two characters long (or the empty string).
- Comprised of the characters specified by alphabet, and the alphabet
  must be limited from 2 to 64 characters.

For your reference see this [LINK](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data)